# Searching worksheet 1, column A for a value, copying it to worksheet 2 and then copying the next three rows

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a 100+ page document containing information on potential funders for our organization. I would like to make an excel macro that extracts contact information from this document and puts it into an Excel spreadsheet. This is what the document looks like:

[image: Here's what the source file looks like]

The addresses are scattered within the text and I've been copying and pasting them into Excel, but since the address is on multiple lines, it pastes into multiple rows of the spreadsheet. I then need to manually parse that string into a usable format.

What I'd like to be able to do is have a macro which searches for the word `"Contact"` and then takes the next three rows in the same column (hence why `VLookUp` won't work for me) and parses them into a normal address format in different columns of one row.

I'd like a macro that turns this:

```
      A
1: Contact:
2: Kate Bull
3: 123 High Road, Whetstone, London
4: N20 8HL
```

Into this:

```
       A               B              C          D       E
1: Kate Bull   123 High Street    Whetstone   London  N20 8HL
```

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your excel data with before and after. One or 2 examples should be fine

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this - I am truly bamboozled and may have to resort to doing this manually (sob!)  I'll upload a screen shot now - it's on the report which comes across in Word and RTF.

Comment: @LucyLord I edited your question to make it more clear and specific. Please take a look at it and make sure that I accurately represented your problem.

Comment: @LucyLord please try to ask questions in above format for future reference so people don’t write useless solutions. The example data you initially provided is not like your photo at all rendering my solution invalid and wasted *volunteer* time. Not a problem, learn as you go kind of thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Seperating your example string by comas will result in 3 strings:

1. `Contact: Kate Bull 123 High Road`
2. `Whetstone`
3. `London N20 8HL`

---

To implement

1. On excel file, `A1 = Original String`, `B1 = Contact`, `C1 = State` `D1 = Country/Zip`
2. Paste you strings on `A2` down
3. Open VBE > Insert `Module` > Paste below code
4. Change sheet name in code line 3 to match your sheet name (`Sheet1` in current code)
5. Run code (Example sheet setup/input/output below)

### [image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSV()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Contact As Range, Contacts As Range, ContactString, i

Set Contacts = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Contact In Contacts
    ContactString = Split(Contact, ", ", , vbTextCompare)
        For i = LBound(ContactString) To UBound(ContactString)
            Contact.Offset(, i + 1) = ContactString(i)
        Next i
    ContactString = ""
Next Contact

End Sub
```

Comment: 1, 2 freddys coming for you.